# Read file as InputStream from Google Drive, throw OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am tring to read a file(70MB) from Google Drive,code like:

Operating environment：  Appengine Standard Environment.

```
Credential credential = getCredentialManager().get(SessionUtil.getUserKey());
Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
InputStream inputStream  = drive.files().get({fileId}).executeMediaAsInputStream();
```

Error Logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.protobuf.ByteString.toByteArray(ByteString.java:615)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertFromPb(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMedia(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:380)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMedia(Drive.java:2727)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAsInputStream(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:523)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMediaAsInputStream(Drive.java:2722)
    at com.deepnet.idigisign.services.plugin.goolgeDrive.GoogleDrive.file(GoogleDrive.java:178)
```

why there is toByteArray() method when I read file as InputStream.
Does any body can help me?

Comment: What instance type are you using (in the versions menu in the developer console) and how much memory the respective instances are using before getting the request (in the instances menu)?

Comment: Instance : B1,   Memory: 128 MB,   CPU :600 MHz,

Comment: And how much memory is the instance normally using (in the instance menu, for a running instance)? I'd try to use an instance size with more memory if I know the file size won't go over 70MB or try to devise a solution which processes the file in chunks.

Comment: Just add memory can not solve this problem. If download a 30GB file, it will throw this exception too.

Comment: Do you know how much free memory you have?